Why does $e^{iqr}$ disappear when $r$ goes to infinity?
Why is the result of this integral calculation like this?
$$
\left[ \frac {e^{-r(m-iq)}} {-(m-iq)}-\frac {e^{-r(m+iq)}} {-(m+iq)} \right]^{\infty}_{r=0}
= \frac {-1} {-(m-iq)}-\frac {-1} {-(m+iq)}
$$
Specifically, why does $e^{iqr}$ disappear when $r$ goes to infinity?

I'm assuming you're integrating in $r.$ Hint: expand $e^{-r(m-iq)}$ using exponent rules and the Euler identity.

Note that $e^{-r s}$ converges to $0$ as $r \rightarrow \infty$ when $\Re s > 0$. This is true since $|e^{- r s}| = e^{-r,\Re s}$.

Sorry, I just dont know why eiqr=0,when r→∞

Remember that $|e^{i \theta}| = 1$ for every real $\theta$. So, as I commented above, when you take the absolute value of $e^{- r s}$, you have $|e^{- r s}| = |e^{- r,\Re s}||e^{-r,i,\Im s}| = e^{-r,\Re s}$. This shows that the imaginary part is irrelevant when taking these sorts of limits. You only have to look at how the exponential of the real part behaves.

Thank u, I get it

Assuming the evaluation is on r, for the first part you should take the limit
$\lim_{r\to\infty} \left[\frac{e^{-r(m-iq)}}{-(m-iq)} - \frac{e^{-r(m+iq)}}{-(m+iq)}\right]$. This limit is indeed zero and, although you can factor it before evaluating the limit, the product will be still zero.
Let's check that it is zero:

First we can factor $e^{-r\left( m - iq \right)}$ as $e^{-r\left( m - iq \right)} = e^{-r m} e^{-r\left(- iq \right)}$.
Secondly, we get that $e^{-r\left(- iq \right)} = e^{irq} = \cos\left(rq\right) + i\sin\left(rq \right)$ because of Euler's formula.
Now we can bound $e^{irq}$ from above since $|e^{irq}|^2 = \cos^2\left(rq\right) + \sin^2\left(rq\right) = 1$.
Finally, assuming that $m \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, we take the limit as $r \to \infty$ for $e^{-rm} e^{irq}$. Since $lim_{r\to\infty} e^{-rm} = 0$ and $e^{iqr}$ is bounded for every $r$ (by $1$), then the limit of the product is zero.

The rest is just evaluating the expression in $r=0$ taking into account the minus sign that comes from the Barrow rule.

Sorry, I just dont know why $e^{iqr} = 0, when \ r → \infty$

thank u, now I get it
